# Python Camelot module does not work offline

Tags: python, opencv, python-camelot

I installed Camelot module for python 3.7 on computer without internet connection, installed dependencies (tkinter & ghostscript).

When I try "import camelot" in jupyter notebook I get error "no module named cv2".
I can't find cv2 module link to download it separately.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

This got rid of the error for me.

```
pip install camelot-py[cv]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Mac with Apple Silicon and the `camelot-py[cv]` method didn't work. I installed **opencv** separately and everything has been working fine so far.

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Answer (score -1):

install comelot-py

```
python -m pip install camelot-py
```